# Elixir: Stream.drop_while generalisation?

Tags: stream, elixir

I'd like to generalise this code but can't see how to do so in a neat way:

```
defmodule Demo do

 defp side_effect(bool, label) do
   if bool do
     IO.puts label
   end
 end

 def go do
  {a,b,c} = {4,8,13}

  [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12] # always in ascending order
  |> Stream.drop_while( fn i -> bool = (i<a); side_effect(bool, "a_#{i}"); bool end ) 
  |> Stream.drop_while( fn i -> bool = (i<b); side_effect(bool, "b_#{i}"); bool end ) 
  |> Stream.drop_while( fn i -> bool = (i<c); side_effect(bool, "c_#{i}"); bool end ) 
  |> Enum.to_list
 end
end
```

When this runs (Demo.go) I get:

```
a_2
a_3
b_4
b_5
b_7
c_8
c_9
c_10
c_11
c_12
[]
```

just as I wished - getting a side effect executed for each element in the input list, with an empty list as final output. 
But is it possible to  generalise this so I can programmatically include (based on a list) as many lines as I like such a:

```
|> Stream.drop_while( fn i -> bool = (i<x); side_effect(bool, "x_#{i}"); bool end )
```

I was hoping not to explore macros if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stream is a data structure, which means you can reduce over it, refining it to a particular set of values on every step:

```
defmodule Demo do
  defp side_effect(var, threshold, label) do
    if var < threshold do
      IO.puts "#{label}_#{var}"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def go do
    values = [a: 4, b: 8, c: 13]

    stream =
      Enum.reduce(values, [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12], fn {k, v}, acc ->
        Stream.drop_while(acc, fn i -> side_effect(i, v, k) end)
      end)

    Enum.to_list(stream)
  end
end
```

You can also explore other solutions. For example, instead of creating a stream for each part of value, you can simple do a filter operation that checks if the value is less than a threshold in a list. Something like this:

```
defmodule Demo do
  defp side_effect(i, values) do
    pair = Enum.find(values, fn {_, v} -> i < v end)

    case pair do
      {k, v} ->
        IO.puts "#{k}_#{i}"
        false
      nil ->
        true
    end
  end

  def go do
    values = [a: 4, b: 8, c: 13]

    [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    |> Stream.filter(fn i -> side_effect(i, values) end)
    |> Enum.to_list()
  end
end
```

I am not sure if you actually need to filter. If not, Stream.map/2 or Stream.each/2 (which is exclusive for side-effects) would work better.

Comment: Although the first solution is beautiful - I don't think it lets me start my processing with a File.stream (in place of the [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12]) as is my plan. So I'll take a look at the second solution.  Elixir brings, for me, a fresh perspective to programming - that combines both beauty and reason - many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, the first solution should work with File.stream too. Just pass the File.stream instead of the list to reduce.